# PHP Conditional Statement if no value exists

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I would like to display `$current_user->first_name` value, but if empty display the `$current_user->user_login` value.

Current code is displaying `first_name` only.

My code:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo 'Hi, ' . ucwords($current_user->first_name) . '!';
```

Comment: `if (empty($current_user->first_name)) {` ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`empty` function](http://php.net/empty):

```
echo empty($current_user->first_name) ? $current_user->user_login : $current_user->first_name
```

`empty` returns `true` if variable is `null`, empty string, 0 etc. So you can read the [ternary condition](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) like "*if first name is empty, display user login, otherwise first name*".

Using a classic condition it would look like this:

```
if (empty($current_user->first_name)) {
    echo $current_user->user_login;
}
else {
    echo $current_user->first_name;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For a one-liner you could use PHP's ternary operator:

`echo isset($current_user->first_name) ? 'Hi, {$current_user->first_name}!' : $current_user->user_login;`

Comment: I would say that the `first_name` property is always set, so your code displays the `first_name` even if it's an empty string.

Comment: Indeed, `emtpy()` it should have been. That's a more severe check than just `isset`. Thanks for the correction.